# iOS parsing JSON from static library returning null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, static-libraries

I'm trying to test out using static libraries, and am calling this method (which is in the static library)

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)parseJSONfromURL:(NSURL *)url{
__strong NSMutableDictionary *json;
[self.delegate isParsing:(url != nil)];
if (url == nil) {
    [NSException raise:NSArgumentDomain format:@"The passed url argument cannot be nil"];
}
NSError *err;
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
if (err) {
    [json setObject:err forKey:@"error"];
}
while (json == nil) {
    NSLog(@"waiting...");
}
[self.delegate isParsing:NO];
[self.delegate didFinishParsing:(json != nil)];
return json;
}
```

I would expect the `while` loop to be infinite since json is returning `null`, but the delegate method `didFinishParsing` gets sent, meaning it isn't `null`.
like this (ACParser is a class in the library)

```
ACParser *p = [[ACParser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
dictionary = [p parseJSONfromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.a-cstudios.com/text.json"]];
```

dictionary is declared like this

```
__strong NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
```

the JSON at that URL is very simple

```
{
"text" : "testing"
}
```

however, every time this is called, in the delegate method `didFinishParsing:`, logging `dictionary` returns `(null)`. What am I doing wrong here? Is it because I'm calling it from a static library?

Comment: Isn't there an infinite loop in that code if `json == nil`?

Comment: That's what I was expecting to happen, which is why I put it there, but it sends something back, it just doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Well it's only ever going to send a `bool` back (`didFinishParsing:` is called with a boolean expression, not the json itself)

Comment: In order words, dictionary is `null` because `true` and `false` (ie `1` and `0`) cannot point to valid `NSDictionary` objects

Comment: I meant to send back a bool, the delegate method is just supposed to let me know that it's done parsing, it's not supposed to send anything back.

Comment: Don't use `__strong`, it wont do anything. All local variables under ARC are strong by default.

Comment: @danielbeard I added that later, just as a test to see if it helped, which it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

`NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]);`

in there and see if it prints out your expected JSON. If it doesnt, your URL is wrong. If it does, then your data isnt being retained. Try instantiating your json variable like this:

`NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err]];`

Answer (score 0):

"`json`" within "`parseJSONfromURL`" is autoreleased / out of scope as soon as that method returns so it never has a chance to get assigned to your strong "`dictionary`" property.
  That's why you are seeing NULL.

Try setting the property *within* your `parseJSONfromURL` method and see if that works, or create a non-autoreleased dictionary and return *that*.

Comment: could you clarify or elaborate on the last two sentences in your original question then?

Comment: I don't understand why `dictionary` is `(null)`

Comment: I tried doing `__strong NSMutableDictionary *json` in `parseJSONfromURL`, but it's still returning null. I can't set the property in the method, because I'm calling it from a library.